# Do we need a head node in a circular linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I need to create a circular linked list. However, I am not sure if I should be having a `head` node. If I include a `head` node I will be able to empty everything easily. But the last element would have to point to the node the `head` is pointing? I am not sure if that would ease things or make it harder.

Comment: Since its circular you wouldn't need a "head" node per se. But you would need a pointer to some node in the list at any given time

Comment: @Mitchel0022 then how would I destroy the list?

Comment: From the node you have a reference to keep freeing the next node until you come full circle. Very similar to a singly linked list but instead of going head to tail you go head to head

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I see, but can't we use the same method for normal linked lists?

Comment: ...yes? Im not sure what you mean

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I mean if that is the case, then why do we implement a `head` node in normal linked lists?

Comment: If its singly linked there is no way to get a reference to the previous nodes if our entry point is not the head. If its doubly linked then any arbitrary node will do, though this makes searching hard as now you must search both ways

Comment: to ceate a circular list you do not need a head node. all elements are pointing to the next node and the last is pointing to the first in that way to find an element you can traverse the entire list until you reach the one you started with. that means that the head can be completly arbitrary every element in the list can act as the head. importent to note that depending on the specific implementation you might want to implement a doubly linked list to shorten execution time of many of the linked list operations

Comment: No matter how a list is implemented, each kind can be used for the same purpose. So, the front of the list may be important if insertion is always to the tail of the list. This may be true even if the list is circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a circular linked-list, a head node (usually termed a **sentinel** node in this case) is only useful if you need to keep track of the insertion order of the elements, because to maintain an order, you need to know the starting point.

For singly-linked lists, this is usually not a consideration, because if insertion order is important, there is not really any point in making the list circular in the first place. For *doubly-linked* lists, however, it becomes useful because then you have a list that you can traverse in either direction: LIFO or FIFO.

For example, an empty, doubly-linked circular list with a sentinel node would look like this:

[image]

The sentinel node is persistent, and usually doesn't carry any payload. As nodes are added, the list begins to look like this:

[image]

As you can see, this allows traversal of the list either in the order the nodes were inserted (using the `next` pointers), or the reverse (using the `prev` pointers).

Again, for a singly-linked list, if the insertion order is needed, then making the list circular defeats the purpose right from the start. If the insertion order is not needed, then there's no point in having a sentinel node you have to carry around, because you never use it. Any old node will do.

Answer (score 4):

A circular linked list doesn't need a *head* node since there's really no head. It *does* however need a pointer into *some* node within the list so you can get to all the elements.

In terms of freeing the list, a normal list scan would stop after processing the node that points to `null`. A circular list is very similar except that you remember the node you started at so you can stop after freeing the one that points to it. Pseudo-code for such a beast would look like:

```
def deleteAll(someNode by reference):
    # Do nothing for empty list.

    if someNode == null:
        return

    # Process each node, stopping after one that points to start node.

    nodeToDelete = someNode
    do:
        nextNode = nodeToDelete.next
        free nodeToDelete
        nodeToDelete = nextNode
    until nodeToDelete == someNode

    # Mark list as empty.

    someNode = null
```