# How to create a doubly circular linked list with a head and tail pointer in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm currently working on the following code in order to create a doubly circular linked list in C. The code does work when given 2 or 3 numbers as argument, but starting a fourth one some numbers start to disappear from the newly created list for some odd reason.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_node
{
        int                             value; // each node contains a integer storing an arbitrary value
        struct s_node   *next;
        struct s_node   *prev;
}                               t_node;

static void     create(t_node **head, t_node **tail, int value, int i)
{
        t_node  *tmp; // create temporary node
        t_node  *result; // create the new node

        tmp = *head;
        result = malloc(sizeof(t_node)); // malloc the new node
        if (!result)
                return ;
        result->value = value;
        result->next = NULL;
        if (*head == NULL) // if the head is NULL, result is the first node to be added
        {
                result->prev = NULL;
                *head = result;
                return ;
        }
        while (tmp->next != NULL && i-- > 0)
                tmp = tmp->next; // parse the linked list until the end
        tmp->next = result; // set result as the next pointer to the last element of the linked list        result->prev = tmp; // set the head has to the previous pointer of the new node
        *tail = result; // tail is now the new node
        (*tail)->next = *head; //link the tail's next pointer to the head to make it circular
        (*head)->prev = *tail; // link the head's previous pointer to make it backwards circular
}

void    save(t_node **head, t_node **tail, int argc, char **argv)
{
        int     i;

        i = 1;
        while (i < argc) // go through the list of given numbers as argument
        {
                create(head, tail, atoi(argv[i]), i); // append a new node to the linked list
                i++;
        }
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        t_node  *head;
        t_node  *tail;
        t_node  *tmp;
        int     i;

        i = 4;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        if (argc == 0)
                return (0);
        save(&head, &tail, argc, argv);
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL && i-- > 0)
        {
                printf("%d - ", tmp->value);
                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        return (0);
}
```

When compiled and executed with two arguments as follows:

```sh
./a.out 10 20
```

returns the following (which is correct):

```sh
10 - 20 - 10 - 20 -
```

When executed with three arguments (10, 20 and 30), the following is printed (which is correct):

```sh
10 - 20 - 30 - 10 -
```

However, when a fourth number is added to the list (10, 20, 30 and 40), the following incorrect list is printed:

```sh
10 - 20 - 40 - 10 -
```

Number 30 disappears, and I really don't understand why. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger to execute your code line by line, checking the variables at each step to be sure their value is what you expect.

Comment: That's definitely a fair point. I guess you are talking about Valgrind or GDB?

Comment: The next node after the newly inserted one is not necessarily the head node. Your `create` seems to be a mix of "insert anywhere" and "insert at end".

Comment: Please explain your code. Which function is supposed to do what? If you describe your understanding it will be easier to tell you where the code acts differently than you think.

Comment: A circular linked list doesn't need a head node since there's really no head. It does however need a pointer into some node within the list so you can get to all the elements.  [Here is the complete descripion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859974/do-we-need-a-head-node-in-a-circular-linked-list)

Comment: I'm talking about a debugger. Any good IDE has a good debugger. I personally mostly work under Windows using [Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/downloads/) which is free for student, hobbyist and open source and has an excellent debugger.

Comment: Sorry for that @Yunnosch, I just added some comments to clarify my code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @fpiette, will look into it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, yes, so the idea is that if the linked list is empty, a new node is added and the head is set to point to it. If not, I iterate through the linked list until the end of it, and then append the new node to it while modifying the tail and head pointers of course.

Comment: Your description surprises me. In a circular double linked list, if empty, the first inserted new node should be pointed to by head **and tail**. If not empty, iterating to the end should be unneeded, because that is what both, tail and head->prev should point to already. Please describe the structure of what you call a double linked circular list, for the case of no node, one node, two nodes and three nodes. Explain where you expect each of your pointers should point to.

Comment: Please explain why you think you need a tail reference in a circular list? If it is truly circular, then the tail in a non-empty list is always equal to `head->prev`, so why would you waste a separate member for that? Why do you test `tmp->next != NULL`? In a circular list there are no `NULL` pointers... Are you really sure you need a *circular* list, or is that a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a a bug in main

```
        int     i;

        i = 4;
```

change to this

```
while (argc-- > -1)
```

do not declare **t**.

another bug is in function create,
change to this

```
        --i;
        while (--i){
                tmp = tmp->next; // parse the linked list until the end
        }
```

I run in windows, it works fine.

EDIT: some variable can declared global

```
typedef struct s_t_node
{
    int value;
    struct s_t_node *prev, *next;
} t_node;

t_node *head=NULL, *tmp=NULL, *tail=NULL;

void create(int value){
        t_node* result=malloc(sizeof(t_node));
        result->value=value;
        result->prev=NULL;
        result->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
                head=result;
                tail=result;
                return;
        }
        tmp=head;
        while(tmp->next)
                tmp=tmp->next;
        tmp->next=result;
        result->prev=tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        if (argc==1)
                return 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
                create(atoi(argv[i]));
        }
        tmp=head;
        while(tmp->next)
                tmp=tmp->next;
        tail=tmp;
        head->prev=tail;
        tail->next=head;
        tmp=head;
        argc-=2;
        do{
                printf("%d - ", tmp->value);
                tmp=tmp->next;
        }while(argc--);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might have something here. I am just not sure what it is.  Please add more descriptive words to describe what is going on, where is the problem?